# R Shiny - how to force submit button to affect not all inputs

Tags: r, shiny

I am facing a problem with `submitButton` usage in my Shiny application (which I use as some time-consuming rendering is done with the data supplied by the app-user). I also use some `radioButtons` with `conditionalPanel` to define the variables group of which user may choose the parameters. Please see the attached image to get the idea (user is selecting a list type, and - based on his list choice - a particular list appears (`conditionalPanel` is working) from which the user is selecting a **parameter**), or run a reprodicible example supplied below.

Of course, only the parameter is a value that is using in rendering an output, and I would like to force a `submitButton` to pass **only** the parameter in an automatic way. The problem is that `submitButton` affects also the `radioButtons` element, which unables the use to choose the desired value (as the values list are not switching).

QUESTION: Is there any way to define which UI elements are to be *stop-from-automatic-update* by `submitButton` so as to solve my problem? Thank you for any help!

**UI:**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(  

   headerPanel("Problem with submit button"),

   sidebarPanel(

     radioButtons("selectionway", "Choose list type", c(number='number', letter='letter')),

     conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.selectionway == 'number'",
  selectInput("numberlist", "Choose NUMBER:", choices = c("11111", "22222", "33333"))
  ),    

     conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.selectionway == 'letter'",
  selectInput("letterlist", "Choose LETTER:", choices = c("A", "B", "C"))
  ),          

    submitButton("submitButton") 

),

  mainPanel(
   verbatimTextOutput("list"),
   verbatimTextOutput("value")  
  )
))
```

**SERVER:**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  selected.value <- reactive({
    if(input$selectionway=="letter"){
      return(input$letterlist)
    } else {
      return(input$numberlist)
    }    
  })

  output$list <- renderText({
    input$selectionway
  })

  output$value <- renderText({    
   selected.value()
  })
```

[image]
    })

Comment: You may want to read up on the `actionButton` and the `isolate` feature of Shiny.